# Search in managed navigation term store, get URL

Tags: search, managed-metadata, managed-navigation, result-source, kql

a customer is asking whether it is possible to use SharePoint (2013 and up) search in a term store and (infer) the URL of any hits.
To make my example more vivid, imagine a term structure like

Navigation

```
 - Group 1 
       - Term 1
       - Term 2
       - Term 3
       - ...
 - Group 2
      - Term 4
      - Term 5
```

Now if I searched for "Term 2" I would like SharePoint to display a result containing the URL.

I tried some KQL like

```
"Term 2" Path:"https://site.contoso.com/" contentclass:STS_Web -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople
```

in the query Editor, but it does not work. If there are any hits, it is only displayed as "Group 1 - https://site.contoso.com/Group 1", but I would like it to be "https://site.contoso.com/Group 1/Term 2".

Also, SharePoint automatically appends `-ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople` which is very annoying. Is that necessary?

Could you please tell me what is wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around:

- Take a normal {SearchBoxQuery}, specify to look for `Title:{SearchBoxQuery}`
- Use `Path:https://path/to/site to narrow search results`
- Create a custom search result page and use the `SharePoint Site` search refiner as Default

This will display only subsites and is totally sufficient. It does not actually solve the Problem but serves the need.